# How to Detect save operation of windows using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a project in C# dot net in which i want to detect any save operation of windows to run my project.
It means that when user do any save operation then project will also create a copy of that saving file.
So please help to detect any save operation in windows

Comment: In Visual Studio? Please be more spesific.

Comment: One instantly wonders; *why*? =)

Comment: There's no global event fired when saves occur. You might use a `FileSystemWatcher`, per Jakub's answer, if all you care about are changes to the *local* machine (and, possibly, any mapped drives), but it won't tell you if someone's saving a file directly to a UNC path. It will also be very busy, and you may not be able to *access* the files which you receive notifications about.

Comment: Do you want to create your own Source Control system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect modification of files using [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class.

If you want to detect file modification in Visual Studio than you might need to write a VS extension.

By the sound of it all you need is a source control software, like **Subversion**, **Mercurial** or **Git**.

Comment: Yes I am using Visual Studio10

Comment: I dont know how to user FileSystemWatcher class to detect save operation

Comment: @SumitRastogi - Have you clicked on a link in my answer? The MSDN page has a good explanation and examples of the class usage.